# Compiler crashing on Xcode 15

Tags: xcode

I recently updated Xcode to 15 and macOS to Sonoma. When I reopened Xcode it kept on crashing after I tried to preview my SwiftUI view files. The report says:

> Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11

I am guessing there is an issue with the compiler but I am not really sure 100% why it is crashing.
When I preview I also get an error message saying that

> ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'

Maybe these errors go hand in hand.

I deleted and downloaded Xcode.
Cleared my logs and cache.
Updated homebrew.
updated dev tools.
Nothing works, still the same issue.